# RevokeDragDrop is not working in all cases

Tags: c#, winapi

I wanted to block drag and drop on other application (skype) (not own by me) using c#. The following code seems to work in my development machine but it is not working in other machines.

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
public static extern int RevokeDragDrop(UIntPtr hwnd);


var result = RevokeDragDrop(hWnd);
Log.Write(ELogLevel.Trace, $"Blocked drag and drop for skype '{hWnd}', result={result}");
```

The response from the Api call RevokeDragDrop returned -2147417842 so it will try again and on second attempt it returned 0 but still it is not blocking file drag and drop in QA machine but it is blocking in my development machine. I checked the handle that I passed which looks okay but still not working. Am I missing anything?

Comment: what do you mean by _"to block other application"_ ?

Comment: The error code is `0x8001010E`, which translates to `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD`.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve, however it is reasonably clear that this is not going to be the solution. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for not having clear question. I want to block drag and drop in other application (Skype).

Comment: @IInspectable Yes. I know the meaning of that error code from https://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/xojo/winerror.shtml but not sure how to handle this in c#. In my dev machine, even if I get this error code from that api, the drag and drop blocking was working.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to change the behaviour of another application from the outside? Doesn't sound like that would be something that would be reasonable to do.

Comment: The application that I am currently working needs this feature which will block file drag and drop in Skype.

Comment: @Prakash If you revoke a your application window which registered as a target of an OLE drag-and-drop operation, can reproduce this error?

Comment: Thanks everyone for you help. Finally able to solve the issue. RevokeDragDrop alone does not seem to work in all cases. I need to use another api RegisterDragDrop as well. So, what I did was, first call RevokeDragDrop and then RegisterDragDrop until I get success response from both api. RegisterDragDrop basically overrides Skype's default IDropTarget by my own custom IDropTarget - that way I can block file drag and drop on Skype.